# Does SmartNav work on Microsoft Windows 11?

Tags: mouse, compatibility, windows-11, accessibility

The SmartNav hardware was discontinued two years ago, before the release of Microsoft Windows 11. In practice, does SmartNav
work on Microsoft Windows 11? I'd prefer to know before upgrading to Windows 11. I couldn't find the answer on the SmartNav forum, which is rather deserted nowadays.

Comment: You would need to connect it and try it. See if it installs?  I cannot see any reason why that would cause issues. It either works or it doesn't.

Comment: @John Thanks, I'd prefer to know before upgrading to Windows 11. But yes if I can't find some answer online, I'll grab some test computer.

Comment: Windows 11 at its core is Windows 10.  Until a pivot by Microsoft mid-2021, what became Windows 11, was more or less going to be Windows 21H2. One of the reasons there are still a few instances of the version indicating it’s Windows 10 not Windows 11. Modern software that supports Windows 10 is nearly guaranteed to support Windows 11.  If it doesn’t you can always rollback to Windows 10.  Device drivers if they don’t support Windows 10 21H2 might have problems.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, good to know, and good news regarding the likelihood of smartnav working with Windows 11